# Rails 4 server fails, Ruby 2.0 segmentation fault, Abort trap 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, osx-mavericks, railstutorial.org, ruby-2.0

I just started going through railstutorial.org and getting my development environment setup. When I got to the section 1.2.5 to run rails server for the fist_app, I type the command and the following printed out:

```
$ rails server
/Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/sqlite3-  <          1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]
```

Then followed by 500 lines of text

> ```
> 0 enumerator.so
> 1 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/enc/encdb.bundle
> 2 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
> 3 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.2.0/rbconfig.rb
> 4 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
> 5 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
> 6 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
> 7 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
> 8 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
> 9 /Users/aaronpflower/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
> ```

Which ended with:

> ```
> [NOTE]
> You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.  
> Bug reports are welcome. 
> For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html  
> Abort trap: 6
> ```

When this first happened double checked the steps leading up to this in the tutorial, since being a beginner that was a high possibility. I typed the follow commands and everything checkout.  (I'm also using OS 10.9.3)

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.5
$ ruby -v 
2.0.0p481
$ rvm -v
1.25.27
$ brew doctor
system ready to brew
```

Through searching some posts have suggested to uninstall sqlite3 and then re-install but I still got the same seg fault message.  Not sure of the next step.

Comment: Have you come across this before? @Chiperific

Comment: Well crafted post. Good job of adding in your environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Rails -v and Ruby -v are correct for this tutorial.

I can also see from the input that your `gemfile` has `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'` in it.

### 1: Have you bundled?

When was the last time you ran `bundle update` or `bundle install`?

How did you go about uninstalling sqlite3? Did you use `$ gem uninstall sqlite3`?
Try uninstalling and then reinstalling the gem.

### 2: - What version manager?

Did you use rvm, rbenv or homebrew to install? Using different version managers for different pieces can create communication issues.

### 3: Did you install Xcode?

This is taken from http://www.railstutorial.org:

---

"As a prerequisite, OS X users may need to install the Xcode developer tools. To avoid the (huge) full installation, I recommend the much smaller Command Line Tools for Xcode.

---

To install Xcode (my recommendation), look it up in the AppStore.

To install Command Line Tools (MHartl's recommendation) - https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

### 4: Are you using `bundle exec`?

Try `bundle exec rails c` and `bundle exec rails s`

### 5: Try 'refreshing' your bundle directory

If `bundle exec` doesn't work
Remove the .bundle/ directory and re-bundle with

```
rm -rf .bundle/ && bundle
```

Comment: I have this same issue. I updated the bundler and reinstalled, but the same issue pops up. I have not uninstalled sqplite3

Comment: @Beast_Code See what running `gem uninstall sqlite3` and then `bundle install` does for you.

Comment: did it. same issue. btw, this is my post i made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438132/bug-segmentation-fault-ruby-2-0-0p481-2014-05-08-revision-45883-x86-64-darwin1

Comment: Only difference I can note is that I installed ruby with rvm not with homebrew.

Comment: @Chiperific it worked.  I uninstalled sqlite3 using `gem uninstall sqlite` and apparently I had a couple versions installed, so I uninstalled both. Then re-installed with `gem install sqlite3` then ran `bundle update` and `bundle install` Thanks.

Comment: `bundle update` was all it took to fix my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, I just switched to a different ruby version

e.g;

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p484
```

and then bundle again.