# BUG Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) x86_64-darwin13.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, homebrew, rbenv

I receive an error when attempting to run `rails s` or `rails c`.

I recently installed ruby and rails via homebrew and rbenv. When I run `rails new project` the app is successfully created. I then do `bundle install` in the appropriate directory and everything updates smoothly, when i then run `rails s` or `rails c`. The following errors come up:

```
|14:48:23| ~ rails c
/Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0031 p:-17563034837610 s:0092 e:000091 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0030 p:---- s:0090 e:000089 CFUNC  :require
c:0029 p:0009 s:0086 e:000085 CLASS  /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:13
c:0028 p:0011 s:0084 e:000083 CLASS  /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12
c:0027 p:0057 s:0082 e:000081 TOP    /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9 [FINISH]
...
```

(keeps going and going)

```
  221 /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/conversions.rb
  222 /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/instance_variables.rb
  223 /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/version.rb
  224 /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/ostruct.rb
  225 /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/generic_object.rb
  226 /Users/jona/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Full bug report http://pastebin.com/ZXDcapw5

Comment: Only difference I can note is that I installed ruby with rvm not with homebrew.

Comment: Yes, but when I posted the question I had not seen the other.

Comment: Try ruby -p451. It may solve your problem.

Comment: i deleted rvm and reinstalled rbenv. That seemed to do it. .. But now I have other issues with another Rails project.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The issue was caused by @Beast_Code not having imploded rvm before starting using rbenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, here is the answer:

Did you used rvm before? Because what I can see from the stacktrace is that both rbenv and rvm are called.

If that is the case, remove rvm completely and reinstall rbenv from scratch.

Comment: ?? I've never had problems with RVM, nor have I ever heard of anyone who has.

Comment: wat. I had plenty of problems and so did most of my colleagues, present and former. I said *majority of people I know* for a reason. Other people have other experiences.

Comment: Then your colleagues are probably atypical. I used RVM for years for all my Rails projects; so did my numerous colleagues. I've probably worked directly with about 50–100 other Ruby devs among my various jobs. None of us have ever had issues with RVM AFAIK. (I did recently switch to rbenv, but not because RVM was giving me problems.) There is no need to spread FUD.

Comment: well, in my experience you are one of the atypical, what can I say.

Comment: What sort of problems have you had?