# Rails server quits with a very long weird non ruby error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I built a photo hosting app where people can upload and sell photos. I just tried to test the site. Everything worked earlier but now when I try to upload a photo (I use carrierwave) the rails server stops (It crash and shuts down). Here's the error I get :

https://gist.github.com/THPubs/7d4bc8b72bd72756898c

The error is so long that I can't even see the start of it. The development log doesn't get this error. Here's the development log :

https://gist.github.com/THPubs/097f9b9e776648c47fa9

What might be the issue? I have never seen an error like this before.

The start of the error :

```
/home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x007f2a1cf61008
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:3675 p:---- s:15040 e:005039 CFUNC  :scan
c:3674 p:0010 s:15036 e:005035 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb:67
c:3673 p:0017 s:15030 e:005029 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:31
c:3672 p:0037 s:15026 e:005025 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:770
c:3671 p:0031 s:15022 e:005020 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:705
c:3670 p:0020 s:15015 e:005014 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13
c:3669 p:0021 s:15008 e:005007 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:669
c:3668 p:0020 s:15002 e:005001 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13
c:3667 p:0030 s:14995 e:004994 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788 [FINISH]
c:3666 p:---- s:14989 e:004988 IFUNC 
c:3665 p:---- s:14987 e:004986 IFUNC 
c:3664 p:---- s:14985 e:004984 CFUNC  :each
c:3663 p:---- s:14983 e:004982 CFUNC  :each_with_index
c:3662 p:---- s:14981 e:004980 CFUNC  :each
c:3661 p:---- s:14979 e:004978 CFUNC  :inject
c:3660 p:0023 s:14975 e:004974 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:786
c:3659 p:0015 s:14968 e:004967 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:644
c:3658 p:0020 s:14963 e:004962 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13
c:3657 p:0030 s:14956 e:004955 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:788 [FINISH]
c:3656 p:---- s:14950 e:004949 IFUNC 
c:3655 p:---- s:14948 e:004947 IFUNC 
c:3654 p:---- s:14946 e:004945 CFUNC  :each
c:3653 p:---- s:14944 e:004943 CFUNC  :each_with_index
c:3652 p:---- s:14942 e:004941 CFUNC  :each
c:3651 p:---- s:14940 e:004939 CFUNC  :inject
c:3650 p:0023 s:14936 e:004935 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:786
c:3649 p:0146 s:14929 e:004928 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:115
c:3648 p:0020 s:14923 e:004922 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13
c:3647 p:0011 s:14916 e:004915 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/arel-6.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:7
c:3646 p:0030 s:14911 e:004910 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb
c:3645 p:0019 s:14905 e:004903 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb
c:3644 p:0021 s:14898 e:004897 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14
c:3643 p:0113 s:14894 e:004893 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:88
c:3642 p:0046 s:14882 e:004881 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:513
c:3641 p:0022 s:14877 e:004876 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:79
c:3640 p:0016 s:14869 e:004868 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:127
c:3639 p:0010 s:14865 e:004864 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310 [FINISH]
c:3638 p:---- s:14863 e:004862 CFUNC  :call
c:3637 p:0036 s:14860 e:004858 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117
c:3636 p:0017 s:14854 e:004853 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555 [FINISH]
c:3635 p:---- s:14851 e:004850 CFUNC  :call
c:3634 p:0021 s:14847 e:004846 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505
c:3633 p:0062 s:14842 e:004841 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92
c:3632 p:0012 s:14835 e:004834 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776
c:3631 p:0007 s:14831 E:0003e8 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310
c:3630 p:0032 s:14827 e:004826 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70
c:3629 p:0043 s:14822 e:004821 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:502
c:3628 p:0008 s:14818 e:004817 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302 [FINISH]
c:3627 p:---- s:14816 e:004815 CFUNC  :call
c:3626 p:0036 s:14813 e:004811 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117
c:3625 p:0017 s:14807 e:004806 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555 [FINISH]
c:3624 p:---- s:14804 e:004803 CFUNC  :call
c:3623 p:0021 s:14800 e:004799 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505
c:3622 p:0062 s:14795 e:004794 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92
c:3621 p:0012 s:14788 e:004787 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776
c:3620 p:0007 s:14784 E:0019e0 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302
c:3619 p:0007 s:14781 e:004780 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142
c:3618 p:0021 s:14777 e:004776 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43
c:3617 p:0010 s:14773 e:004772 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29
c:3616 p:0010 s:14769 e:004768 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291
c:3615 p:0014 s:14767 e:004766 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347
c:3614 p:0069 s:14765 e:004764 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb
c:3613 p:0017 s:14761 e:004760 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220
c:3612 p:0014 s:14756 E:0016f8 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344
c:3611 p:0007 s:14752 E:001368 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291
c:3610 p:0016 s:14748 e:004747 METHOD /home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/app/models/photo.rb:78
c:3609 p:0012 s:14745 e:004744 LAMBDA /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432 [FINISH]
c:3608 p:---- s:14740 e:004739 CFUNC  :call
c:3607 p:0050 s:14735 e:004734 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228 [FINISH]
c:3606 p:---- s:14729 e:004728 CFUNC  :call
c:3605 p:0012 s:14725 e:004724 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506 [FINISH]
c:3604 p:---- s:14722 e:004721 CFUNC  :each
c:3603 p:0030 s:14719 e:004718 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506
c:3602 p:0062 s:14714 e:004713 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92
c:3601 p:0012 s:14707 e:004706 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776
c:3600 p:0007 s:14703 E:000f50 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302
c:3599 p:0007 s:14700 e:004699 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142
c:3598 p:0021 s:14696 e:004695 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43
c:3597 p:0010 s:14692 e:004691 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29
c:3596 p:0010 s:14688 e:004687 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291
c:3595 p:0014 s:14686 e:004685 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347
c:3594 p:0069 s:14684 e:004683 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb
c:3593 p:0017 s:14680 e:004679 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220
c:3592 p:0014 s:14675 E:000ac8 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344
c:3591 p:0007 s:14671 E:0008d8 METHOD /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291
c:3590 p:0016 s:14667 e:004666 METHOD /home/pubudu/Projects/istockseller/app/models/photo.rb:78
c:3589 p:0012 s:14664 e:004663 LAMBDA /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432 [FINISH]
c:3588 p:---- s:14659 e:004658 CFUNC  :call
c:3587 p:0050 s:14654 e:004653 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228 [FINISH]
c:3586 p:---- s:14648 e:004647 CFUNC  :call
c:3585 p:0012 s:14644 e:004643 BLOCK  /home/pubudu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506 [FINISH]
c:3584 p:---- s:14641 e:004640 CFUNC  :each
```

Comment: what's your ruby version ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady it's  ruby 2.2.1

Answer (score 2):

That's a segfault - Ruby (or one of your libraries with native extensions) has hit a bug.

You should check to see if there are newer versions of any of your libraries with extensions available. If not, then consider trying to narrow down exactly which instruction is causing the issue, and submit a bug report to the project maintainer responsible.

If you can, see if you can find the start of the error message (you may need to increase your terminal buffer size), as it may contain critical information about the source of the error.

Edit: According to your stack trace, your error is here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/utils.rb#L67

This is just a `String#scan` call, which would suggest that this is a Ruby error. Consider posting a bug report at http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

You may also try upgrading or downgrading your version of Ruby, and see if the issue solves itself.

Comment: Just found the start of the error. Posted it above. Seems to be a postgresql issue

Comment: So for now will it be fixed if i downgrade ruby? Or should I downgrade the postgresql gem?

Comment: I would try downgrading Ruby to the latest in the 2.1 series, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This means that ruby itself crashed. It shouldn't be possible to trigger this from pure ruby code so this  usually indicates one of a few things:

- a bug in ruby itself. The 2.2 series of ruby is still quite new, with some big changes to areas such as garbage collection, so it's possible that some sharp edges remain.
- a bug in a gem that has a native extension. It's easy enough for example to write a native extension that crashes when given an invalid argument
- an installation problem. If ruby or a native extension was compiled against one version of a library but loads another version at runtime then bad stuff can happen. This might also happen if environment problems cause the gems from a different ruby version to be loaded.

In all cases the earlier part of the error message (which will have a stacktrace) is important. If it's your terminal scrollback limit that is preventing your from seeing the start, then increase it.

Hopefully this allows you to narrow down the problem to a small reproducible example. If it is one of the first 2 problems then the next step is probably to start looking through the issue trackers of either ruby or the gems you have identified as the culprits

Comment: Looks to be a postgresql problem! Added the start of the error to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into these

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415120/rails-4-server-fails-ruby-2-0-segmentation-fault-abort-trap-6)

[link2](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4050)

[This is for Ruby 1.9.3-p0 but please try for your issue](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/01/fixing-a-segmentation-fault-in-ruby-193/)

Comment: @EApubs, Did you try above links.