# The localhost page isn’t working ruby rails puma osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, localhost

I have been working on a rails app for months and then, all of a sudden the pumas server does not work on my laptop.  I've tried different older branches (in case I changed something) I've uninstalled and reinstalled ruby.  Nope.  It DOES work if I do a fresh pull and load it on my desktop, so it seems to be something on my laptop?   I am really lost.

Here's what I've done already:

- Restarted the computer
- reinstalled ruby
- Tried puma
- Tried rails s
- Tried different branches to see if something I did yesterday somehow broke it
- reinstalled gems

The error is:

```
The localhost page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
```

However, right before it was running this error, it ran a Request time out error, if that matters.

What I really don't understand is why it's only happening on one computer.

I am running Ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.6

UPDATE

It DOES running rails server and not puma.

The problem is, I'm using foreman to start sidekiq with my server, and that's how I debug sidekiq queues.  Strangely,  sidekiq still works, but I can't access the localhost page.

This is my procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -q default -q mailers
```

Again, I haven't changed anything with puma and rails s works fine.

Comment: change anything in `/etc/hosts` lately?  if you change ports with `rails s -p 3010` and go to `localhost:3010` does it work?

Comment: no, that's what's so weird.  I did nothing before the error except edit a config file in my app and some front end.

Comment: when I try 3010 I get 
`Request ran for longer than 25000ms`  which is the error I was getting for awhile before the other error

Comment: Perhaps some help here? Old question, but might still be relevant if you really have run into a Ruby bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415120/rails-4-server-fails-ruby-2-0-segmentation-fault-abort-trap-6